# How can i get progress bar for amazon multiple file upload s3 android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, progress-bar, multiple-file-upload

now am using MultipleFileUpload method .how can i get progress bar for that .please some help me.

```
 MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadFileList(
            "backetname", s3_path, myDir_temp, collection_file, metadataProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS SDK for Android and Check the AWS docs for the same: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

With the Transfer Utility, the download() and upload() methods return a TransferObserver object. This object gives access to:

The state (now specified as an enum)
The total bytes transferred thus far
The total bytes to transfer (for easily calculating progress bars)
A unique ID that you can use to keep track of distinct transfers
Given the transfer ID, this TransferObserver object can be retrieved from anywhere in your app, including if the app is killed. It also lets you create a TransferListener, which will be updated on state or progress change, as well as when an error occurs.

To get the progress of a download or upload, call setTransferListener() on your TransferObserver. This requires you to implement onStateChanged, onProgressChanged, and onError. For example:

```
TransferObserver transferObserver = download(MY_BUCKET, OBJECT_KEY, MY_FILE);
transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
        int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
        //Display percentage transfered to user
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
        // do something
    }

});
```

Comment: this one for single file upload.am correct? .i need progress bar for multiple file upload. i mention upload method in question.

Comment: If you go according to the AWS docs, you can see that you will have to call the Listener and it should work

Comment: i tired listener function also.its called only once.so starting state only we get..